# Building multi-module project from Maven into one war file

Tags: maven

My question has been asked before, which I know, but I think that I am trying to do something slightly different, where existing answers are not appropriate.

Essentially, I do want to have multiple projects in Eclipse that will be built (preferably) into one final WAR file.  Ideally like this:

```
root - pom.xml
|___ java-app
|___ web-service-v1
|___ web-service-v2
|___ web-service-v3
|___ rest-service
|___ batch-service
```

Imagine the Java App as the actual application, and each additional component runs as a decoupled view layer for the Java App itself.  Ultimately, the Java application will be running in a tomcat instance, with the different modules providing their services.  I would like all the different modules also to run in the same Spring container.

I don't know that running in Maven modules is the best way of doing this, but I would really prefer to have each component in a separate Eclipse project that ultimately get built together.

Can anyone provide any suggestions as to how I would use Maven to build this?

Comment: A module in maven is a pretty loose construct; they can be as related or unrelated as you like.  You certainty can do what you're looking to do.  What are your reservations?

Comment: I'm just confused about how to set up the different pom.xml files.  the parent project must be build as "pom", but it would be imperative for me to have the Parent project be a WAR, with my configuration files and commons stuff. For example, multiple modules need a JMX console which I have configured through Spring.  I assume the parent project will need to contain this so that the individual modules can remain decoupled.

Comment: I'd also like to be able to configure which eclipse projects get included in the build, perhaps as a goal, if that is possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just make a separate war module:

```
root - pom.xml (packaging: pom!!!)
|___ java-app
|___ web-service-v1
..
+--- mod-war (pom.xml)
```

and put the dependencies of the modules you would like to have added to the war file into the pom and that's it.

Comment: I actually ended up doing something similar this, where I have one project that is built as a WAR that depends on my other projects, then I have all my configuration for Spring and tomcat in the WAR project.  Ended up working great.  I might switch to this though, where the WAR project only has one dependency, which includes different modules.

Answer (score 3):

The main Maven idea is that each module must produce a single build artifact (e.g. a jar or a war file). The parent pom is usually responsible for global configuration and dependency management and also for a proper module orchestration. If your final result need to be a WAR file, then last module in the list will be the web application. The other modules could supply classes that war file depend on.

There are more complicated build structures, but above one should be sufficient for you.

Comment: What actually makes it tricky, is that there are some configurations that need to span each module, so I don't think I can use a POM type project as the parent.

Comment: @Mous - I think you can do what you need to do.  Check out the following link, and try to really get the different between project inheritance and project aggregation.  That made all the difference for me.  I think once that makes sense you might be able to see how maven can handle the config that you want.  http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat dated, but hope this additional info helps someone.

@Mouscellaneous An example of keeping Spring configs in each module and referencing them from the web.xml can be found [here in the Sonatype book](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule-web-spring-sect-simple-web.html). I guess this is what you are looking for.