# How to deploy maven project with parent packaging pom

Tags: maven, jboss7.x

I'm trying to deploy a maven web app with two modules and I tried using mvn package to get a war. Instead I got a pom.xml for the parent app and two jars for the submodules. That's...that's just great. How do I deploy that? I was expecting a war. Also, trying to deploy to jboss.

Edit: What goes in web.xml?

Comment: "What goes in web.xml?" is kind of a loaded question. We don't really know if you're using servlets, JSF, EJB's, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your sub-modules declare `<packaging>war</packaging>`.
If you define not a packaging-type maven will choose jar as default.

If your parent-pom defines your `modules` it should be a POM as packaging (guess the parent-pom is in 99.9% cases POM as packaging-type). So as result for the parent-pom you get just a pom.xml.

For deploy you need to specifiy a `<distributionManagent>`.

```
<distributionManagement>
  <repository>
    <id>corp1</id>
    <name>Corporate Repository</name>
    <url>scp://repo/maven2</url>
  </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

For username and password i prefer to declare a `<server>` in the ~/.m2/settings.xml
so your password is not public for everyone.

I recommend to look into the maven-book from [Sonatype](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/).

If this don't help, please edit your post and insert your POMs.

Comment: Just to add there is also a JBoss AS maven plugin you can use to deploy your application, https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/

Answer (score 0):

1. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845178/building-multi-module-project-from-maven-into-one-war-file) is a good reference for  building multi-module project from Maven into one war file.
2. The war file can be deployed via [jboss-maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jboss-maven-plugin/examples/deploy-undeploy-examples.html).