# Maven JAR project with WAR project layout?

Tags: maven, netbeans

I hope the title is not to confusing. I am developing a library to be used in JSF projects. The library will be packaged as a JAR. The project is currently setup as a war and i am able to create the JAR using the jar:jar goal. Having a WAR project enables me to autodeploy changes and run them instantly whereas a JAR project would require 2 builds: One build for the JAR itself and one for a test webapp that uses this jar.

However, since the project is setup as a WAR, the artifact deployed to my local maven repo is also a WAR but the JAR is the desired artifact. Is there a way to create a setup that fulfills this requirement?

Just for clarification: I know the common way is to have a JAR project and a separate WAR project that depends on the JAR. I don't want to use this setup because of the negative impact on turnaround times when 2 artifacts need to be build.

Any hints or experience on this?

Here is my current pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>mygroupid</groupId>
<artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>mylibrary</name>

<licenses>
    <license>
        <name>The Apache Software License, Version 2.0</name>
        <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
        <distribution>repo</distribution>
        <comments>A business-friendly OSS license</comments>
    </license>
</licenses>

<properties>
    <netbeans.compile.on.save>all</netbeans.compile.on.save>
    <org-netbeans-modules-projectapi.jsf_2e_language>Facelets</org-netbeans-modules-projectapi.jsf_2e_language>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <netbeans.hint.deploy.server>Tomcat</netbeans.hint.deploy.server>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- my dependencies -->
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>                
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources> 
        <resource> 
            <directory>src/main/resources/</directory> 
            <targetPath>META-INF</targetPath> 
        </resource> 
    </resources>         
</build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your project a multi-module project with a parent pom.xml and two children: the jar and the war. Put all your java sources in the jar project and have your war project depend on the sibling jar project. Then you can run `mvn package` from the parent pom module and build everything in one step.

See also: [Building multi-module project from Maven into one war file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845178/building-multi-module-project-from-maven-into-one-war-file)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am aware of multi module builds. Having everything in a single Maven based project allows automatic deployments when code is changed. I find this feature very valuable but it seems like there is no way to have this with a multi module build. Anyway, multi module builds seem to be the standard way to organize code, so I'll stick to it for now.

Comment: There could be another way: [Maven Build Helper plugin `build-helper:attach-artifact`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html).

Comment: BTW what tool are you using to automatically deploy after a code change?

Comment: Eclipse and Netbeans can do that. At least for static files like XHTML or JS this very helpful